# What software can display raw bitmaps on Linux?

Tags: binary, image-processing

I have a raw file but I don't know the pixel format or the width of the image. I need a tool that can quickly display the data and allow me to try different formats easily. An example of such a tool for Windows would be [7yuv](http://datahammer.de/). What software exists for this task on Linux?

Note: This has nothing to do with digital camera raws, which is frustrating my attempts to use Google to answer this question.

[image: 7yuv]

Comment: I'm guessing there are lots available (a quick search in the repos will propably give you more than enough results). The one I prefer though is digikam (I haven't tried many others though). I'm also certain that GIMP has a plugin that allows viewing and manipulating raw files.

Comment: Searching the repos finds nothing appropriate. Additionally, these aren't camera raws as stated in the question.

Comment: Use can use 7yuv in Linux also through WINE. It has a silver rating so it will probably run just fine... if you can't find any linux native alternatives, give it a try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out Gimp can do this. Just open the file as raw, and you get this helpful dialog that allows you to preview the image:

[image]

Comment: How do you open the raw data file?

Comment: File->Open then change the file type to raw.

Comment: It's only for RGB. how do you open grayscale (8bit) raw format?

Comment: open do you open grayscale?

Answer (score 6):

**`convert` from ImageMagick**

E.g., an 8-bit 2x3 grayscale:

```
printf '\x00\xFF\x88\xFF\x00\xFF' > in.bin
```

Then:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 3x2+0 gray:in.bin out.png
```

Command explanation:

- `-depth 8`: each color has 8 bits
- `-size 2x3+0`: `2x3` image. `+0` means starting at offset 0 in the file. If there are metadata headers, you can skip them with the offset.
- `gray:in.bin`: the input file is `in.bin`, and the format is `gray`, as defined at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php This weird notation is used because ImageMagick usually determines the format from the extension, but here there is no extension.

**How to view such tiny outputs like this example**

The problem now is how to view the such a tiny 3x2 output accurately. A direct `eog`:

```
eog out.png
```

is not very good because the image is too small, and if you zoom in a lot `eog` uses a display algorithm that mixes up pixels continuously, which is better for most pictures, but not for such a tiny image.

One good possibility is to run:

```
convert out.png -scale 300x out2.png
```

or directly in one go with:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 3x2+0 gray:in.bin -scale 300x out.png
```

`-scale` is needed instead of `-resize`, since `-resize` mixes pixel colors continuously up much like `eog` by default.

Output:

[image]

Anther option is to view it in Gimp:

```
gimp out.png
```

Image editors such as Gimp must show every single pixel separately if you zoom in enough.

**RGB example**

```
printf '\xFF\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x00\x00\x00\xFF' > in.bin
convert -depth 8 -size 3x1+0 rgb:in.bin out.png
```

or with the `-scale` to make it more viewable:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 3x1+0 rgb:in.bin -scale 300x out.png
```

[image]

Related:

- https://superuser.com/questions/294270/how-to-view-raw-binary-data-as-an-image-with-given-width-and-height

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, ImageMagick 6.8.9.

Comment: This is a decent solution. I scripted it up with my inputs, and it works all the time.

Comment: how do i convert a mono image, 10bit, that each pixel is padded into a 16bit (2 bytes)?

Comment: @NathanB I don't know and couldn't find easily after a quick Google, I'd just preprocess it in Python, let me know if you find a built-in way

Comment: Yes found the way: convert -depth 16 -size 2688x1944+0 gray:a.png

Answer (score 0):

this python snippet does it:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


raw_img = np.fromfile("image",  dtype=np.uint8)
l = int(np.sqrt(raw_img.shape[0]/4))  # for a l x l square image
Image.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=(l, l), data=raw_img).show()
```